# Cant get 'access_token' from httpcontext asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, jwt, adal

I have problem with getting a token from my `httpContext` in Asp.Net Core 2.0 project. I have implicit ADAL authorization on front part where I'm getting the token and sending it in a header when accessing my API. Authentication is going well, but when I want to get token for a request to the Microsoft Graph api I'm getting `null`.

My `Startup` authentication part:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            AuthenticationOptions authSettings = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Get<AuthenticationOptions>();
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidAudiences = new List<string> { authSettings.ClientId, authSettings.AppIdUri }
            };
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
            options.Audience = "**";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;

            options.SaveToken = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddMvc();
```

The method where I need to get a token:

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        //Get the access token used to call this API
        string token = await httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        //We are passing an *assertion* to Azure AD about the current user
        //Here we specify that assertion's type, that is a JWT Bearer token
        string assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

        //User name is needed here only for ADAL, it is not passed to AAD
        //ADAL uses it to find a token in the cache if available
        var user = httpContext.User;
        string userName = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Upn) ?? user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

        var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token, assertionType, userName);

        //Construct the token cache
        var cache = new DistributedTokenCache(user, _distributedCache, _loggerFactory, _dataProtectionProvider);

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authSettings.Authority, cache);
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_authSettings.ClientId, _authSettings.ClientSecret);
        //Acquire access token
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCredential, userAssertion);
        //Set the authentication header
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(result.AccessTokenType, result.AccessToken);
    }
```

In the part of `await httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` it's returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

im sry for disturbing, solution was quite easy. And ty for your attention.

```
httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var token);
```